# Is call by reference safe in this C++ example?

Tags: c++

Comming from Java I would like to implement the following "test multiple implementations" idiom in C++

```
void testMethod() {
    List veryBigList = createNewRandomList(10000);
    Algo algo = createAlgo(veryBigList);
    algo.run();
}

// this can be overwritten from a subclass to test against different algo
Algo createAlgo(List list) {
    Algo a(list);
    return a;
}

List createNewRandomList(int size) {
    List l = new ArrayList(size);
    // fill list with random objects
    return l;
}
```

I'm a bit lost how to do this the right way in C++ ... when I'm doing it this way:

```
void test_method() {
    vector<string> big_list(10000);
    init_random_list(big_list);
    algo my_algo = create_algo(big_list);
    my_algo.run();
}

algo create_algo(vector<string> list) {
    algo a(list);
    return a;
}

void init_random_list(vector<string> list) {
    // fill list with random objects        
}
```

then what will C++ do? Will it copy the full list to go to create_algo and then on return it'll copy the algo (and the list again)??

But when using call by reference I would access the reference in test_method outside of the scope of algo causing a lot trouble and violating the [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) principle, right?

I know for some implementations of C++ they optimize speed for call by value according to [this doc](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/), but can I rely on that for g++ and visual c++?

Comment: Rather than doing : `vector<string> big_list(10000);` , do `vector<string> big_list; big_list.reserve(10000)` , will be more efficient :)

Comment: @Mr.Anubis and which gives different behaviour.

Comment: @KillianDS What kind of behavior you're ref to? excluding first one will call default constructor 10000 times and second doesn't

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: The first creates a vector with 10000 elements in it, the second with 0 elements in it (and reserves memory for 10K), seems quite different to me. As there is nowhere an indication that the 10k elements will be readded/overwritten your code change is significant.

Comment: Without explaining what you are trying to achieve, it is impossible to provide an answer. What does the `algo` object do with the object that it receives? How long do you need the different objects to life? How is the copy constructor of `algo` defined?

Comment: @KillianDS second one doesn't reserves 10k memory but reserves memory for 10k elements

Comment: @Mr.Anubis you are missing the point that Killian is trying to make, the semantics are different because after the operation in the original case `size()==10000` while in your modified version `size()==0`, and moreover `v[0]` is undefined behaviour in your case.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas The algo object stores the list and uses it in the run method. but it needs to be created outside of algo as the list will be changed from a different method not covered here (I'll update the post to reflect that). the list and the algo needs to live for the whole test_method. how to define the copy constructor would be another question for you :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas That way I agree :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the code is exactly as you posted, and that `algo` can be modified to store a reference, then you probably want to pass and store a reference.

Comment: Thanks this helps. For further clarification (of my virtual const ;) Java brain): this means that an user of my algo class needs to know that it has to construct and destruct the list itself?

Comment: Would you show me how the copy constructor of the algo class can look like? The creating method is changed to this here, right? algo create_algo(vector<string>* list)

Comment: .@DavidRodriguez nice blog - to be investigated :)

Comment: @Karussell No, using a reference means that algo knows the list already exists and doesn't need special treatment.

Comment: @Karussell: The blog... well, it is a bit dead now. I hope to retake it in some time, but I have had too many changes in my life in the last few months to get any time to write.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why not just call `algo my_algo(biglist)` in `test_method`, bypassing the call to `create_algo`?

But yes, you're right, this will create copies (in principle, although in practice it may not, if you're lucky). So the real question is, what do you do in the algo with the list? E.G. if you treat the list as read-only, using references is fine.

If not, simply changing the call to create_algo to use a reference will prevent one (potential) copy.

Comment: Hmmh, I need to overwrite that create_algo method as I want to use the same test for different implementations of my algorithm.

Comment: But when using call by reference and doing the same in the copy constructor of the algo - wouldn't C++ release the storage of the biglist twice times then? One time for "reaching end of algo" and one for "reaching end of vector<string>"? I'm still confused ...

Comment: @Karussell That depends on what you have inside algo. You didn't show us the constructor and destructor.

Answer (score 0):

The semantics of `algo` appear to be a bit unusual. It looks like a functor class, and you are passing and storing one argument at construction time. Most often, C++ functor classes are stateless.

I think it would be more canonical to do

```
std::function< algo_result( algo_args ) > // return generic functor type
create_algo(std::vector<std::string> &list) {
    return std::bind( algo(), std::ref( list ) ); // store reference
    // result of std::bind implicitly converts to std::function
}
```

`std::bind` returns a stateful functor object, and it works together with `std::ref` to allow you to keep a reference inside that object without manually defining how the reference is stored. Now the `algo` object and the reference are copied inside the `std::function`, but that should be cheap.

On the other hand, if `algo` is truly stateful and requires a `list` to exist, it should be an argument to the constructor and you should not use a factory function.

Comment: @Karussell: I'm suggesting that if possible, `algo` should not have `list` as a member. Currently you have a function which only calls the constructor, which is wrong. Either use the constructor without a wrapper function, or remove the member, take an additional parameter in `algo::operator()`, and use `bind` to pass `list` to that parameter. The latter option is illustrated here, so I also removed the argument to the constructor of `algo`.